# Something broke my scanning: cannot scan anymore on Canon MF8200 (MF8280Cw)

Tags: scanner, sane

I am running Xubuntu 20.04 with now 5.4.0-51-generic kernel on a Thinkpad T480. Up until recently I could scan without any problem on my Canon MF8280Cw in LAN / WLAN. Scanner still works with other devices (a laptop with Fedora, from the Xubuntu live USB and from Windows) but not with my laptop. What is strange is that `sudo sane-find-scanner` finds the scanner, but `scanimage -L`, `simple-scan` and `xsane` do not. With or without `sudo`. I do not know what broke it and I do not know in what direction to investigate it further... Help!

Output of `sane-find-scanner` (no `sudo`)

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x2109/0x0711 at 004:005: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x8153 at 004:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x0411 at 004:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x0411 at 004:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x046d/0xc52b at 003:006: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x5411 at 003:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x5411 at 003:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x06cb/0x009a at 001:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04f2/0xb604 at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0a2b at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

output of `sudo sane-find-scanner`

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x0bda [Realtek], product=0x8153 [USB 10/100/1000 LAN]) at libusb:004:004
found USB scanner (vendor=0x06cb, product=0x009a) at libusb:001:004
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

scanner is found twice for LAN (`libusb:004:004`) and WLAN (`libusb:001:004`)

`scanimage -L` error:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

`simple-scan` and `xsane` are giving similar erorrs: no scanner found

This is the status of `saned.socket`

```
saned.socket - saned incoming socket
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/saned.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (listening) since Thu 2020-10-15 12:55:32 CEST; 2s ago
   Triggers: ● saned@0.service
     Listen: [::]:6566 (Stream)
   Accepted: 0; Connected: 0;
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 38167)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/saned.socket

Okt 15 12:55:32 pashopt systemd[1]: Listening on saned incoming socket.
```

What I have already tried is to uninstall completely `sane` (include the systemd service and socket) and to reinstall.

Sane packages were updated somewhere at end of September (29th or so) and I assume somewhere there is the culprit as I have not scanned for a while.

Thanks!

p.s. sorry for the long post :)

p.s.1. the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 2109:0711 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 413c:2010 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:1003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera (1280x720@30)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have continued digging and found a solution. Still it seems to be a non standard one but it's working. What I have done is I have edited `/etc/sane.d/pixma.conf` and added the line with the settings for `mfnp` (I still need to read to see what this exactly is...) as following:

```
fmnp://my.scanner.ip.address/timeout=1500
```

saved and restarted saned

```
sudo systemctl restart saned.socket
```

I hope this will help somebody and will save them smashing their head against the keyboard, monitor, scanner..

Comment: Give the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: i have added the output of `lsusb` to the original post. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From `sudo scanimage -L` Vlad gets:

> found USB scanner (vendor=0x0bda [Realtek], product=0x8153 [USB 10/100/1000 LAN]) at libusb:004:004
> found USB scanner (vendor=0x06cb, product=0x009a) at libusb:001:004

Looking at the `lsusb` output: product=0x8153 is an ethernet adapter and product=0x009a is a Synaptics device. In other words, `sane-find-scanner` hasn't found found any scanners at all! Also, `sane-find-scanner` is not an appropriate command to use with a scanner connected directly to the network .

If the pixma driver backend works for you, that's fine. However, I would suggest taking a look at [sane-airscan](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan). Should [you install it](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/), I would appreciate knowing what you get for `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover`.

Comment: hi, since the scanner is a network scanner isn't it normal that `sane-find-scanner` finds it on the network (ethernet adapter)? p.s. The Synaptics device `(vendor=0x06cb, product=0x009a) at libusb:001:004` is a fingerprint scanner... so also a scanner :)

Comment: The manual for sane-find-scanner (`man sane-find-scanner`) says: sane-find-scanner  is a command-line tool to find SCSI and USB scanners...

Comment: so, I have commented the line in pixma.conf and installed `sane-airscan`. `scanimage -L` gives me the same error with "no scanners were identified". `airscan-discover` returns a (empty) line with `[devices]`. Same happens with `sudo airscan-discover`.